# Can I install pg_dump without installing postgres on Alpine?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, alpine-linux

I have tried to install `pg_dump` as part of installation of `postgres-client`, however it does not include `pg_dump`.

Can `pg_dump` be installed without a full installation of postgres on Alpine Linux?

Comment: Note for future readers - this is no longer the case: `apk add postgresql-client` installs `pg_dump`

Answer (score 30):

No - to install `pg_dump` and associated utilities, you'll need to run `apk add postgresql`, which will install the full PostgreSQL suite.

The installed size is currently 12.1mb (for v9.6.0-r1) vs just 451kb for `postgresql-client`, so it's definitely bigger. If you're using Alpine in Docker, that might not be a big deal. If you're using it in an embedded device where size matters, you could simply copy over `pg_dump` or whatever else you need.

**Edit:** This is no longer true. `apk add --no-cache postgresql-client` is sufficient.

Comment: Is this still the case for alpine? [This link](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=pg_dump&path=&name=&branch=edge&repo=main&arch=x86) seems to indicate that pg_dump is now part of postgresql-client

Comment: Indeed `apk add --no-cache postgresql-client` is now enough for the pg_dump binary

Answer (score 23):

The answer to this question is ***yes***.

- [postgresql-client](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/postgresql14-client), 2.86 MB installed, *[does contain](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=postgresql14-client&arch=x86&repo=main)* the `pg_dump` command
- [postgresql-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/postgresql-dev), 9.05 MB MB installed, *does not* contain `pg_dump` but is required by `psycopg2`.
- [postgresql](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/postgresql), 15.02 MB installed *does not* contain `pg_dump`